# ES6 Promises in Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ecmascript-6, chai, es6-promise

I'm using [this polyfill for ES6 promises](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) and Mocha / Chai.

My assertions for the promises are not working.  The following is a sample test:

```js
it('should fail', function(done) {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(false);
    }).then(function(result) {
        assert.equal(result, true);
        done();
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

When I run this test it fails due to timeout.  The assertion failure that was thrown in the then block is caught in the catch block.  How can I avoid this and just throw it straight to Mocha?

I could just throw it from the catch function, but then how would I make assertions for the catch block?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)?

Comment: shouldn't your catch be, ```console.log(err);done(err);```?

Comment: @thefourtheye promise assertions are what i'm looking for.  Thanks, that's a good resource.

Comment: @mido22 the issue then is making assertions about the rejections that are made by the promise.  But, as thefourtheye said above, Mocha apparently has this feature built in.

Comment: If you're asserting that the promise succeeds and you don't need to assert anything else, you can just return the promise value without calling `.then()` or `.catch()`. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by using [Chai as Promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/).

It allows you to make assertions about the resolution and rejections of promises:

- `return promise.should.become(value)`
- `return promise.should.be.rejected`

Comment: Hi, 

Is it possible to provide paste your code for the above question using  chai as promised?

Answer (score 4):

If your Promise has a failure, it will only call your catch callback. As a result, Mocha's done callback is never called, and Mocha never figures out that the Promise failed (so it waits and eventually times out).

You should replace `console.log(err);` with `done(err);`. Mocha should automatically display the error message when you pass an error to the done callback.

Comment: How can I then make assertions about the rejections that are made by the promise?

Comment: What do you mean by this? Is the promise supposed to succeed or fail? If it's supposed to succeed, I don't see why you'd need to assert anything about the rejection as long as you ensure that it doesn't happen.

Comment: Because you would want to make assertions about the conditions under which the promise is rejected.

Answer (score 2):

A pattern I use in my Mocha/Chai/es6-promise tests is the following:

```
it('should do something', function () {

    aPromiseReturningMethod(arg1, arg2)
    .then(function (response) {
        expect(response.someField).to.equal("Some value")
    })
    .then(function () {
        return anotherPromiseReturningMethod(arg1, arg2)
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        expect(response.something).to.equal("something")
    })
    .then(done).catch(done)

})
```

The last line is odd looking, but calls Mocha's done on success or on error.

One problem is if the last then returns something, I then need to noop()* before both the `then` and the `catch`:

```
it('should do something', function () {

    aPromiseReturningMethod(arg1, arg2)
    .then(function (response) {
        expect(response.someField).to.equal("Some value")
    })
    .then(function () {
        return anotherPromiseReturningMethod(arg1, arg2)
    })
    .then(_.noop).then(done).catch(done)

})
```

*Lodash's noop().

Would love to hear any critiques of this pattern.

Comment: Personally I would not return anything from any of the onFullFilled handlers in test cases.  But to safeguard from the return values a `.then(done.bind(null, null), done)` seems a bit more terse for me.